# How do I route incoming messages on server to an html page in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, tcp

Basically, I am trying to display incoming data on the server's port to an HTML web page.This code display incoming messages plus who joined or left but on the console window and I am trying to display these messages on the web page.Please help.Thank you.

Server Side code-

```
   // Load the TCP Library
   net = require('net');

    // Keep track of the chat clients
   var clients = [];

   // Start a TCP Server
   net.createServer(function (socket) {

   // Identify this client
   socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

  // Put this new client in the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Send a nice welcome message and announce
  socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
  broadcast(socket.name + " joined \n", socket);

  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
  broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket);
  });

  // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
  socket.on('end', function () {
  clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
  });

  // Send a message to all clients
  function broadcast(message, sender) {
  clients.forEach(function (client) {
    // Don't want to send it to sender
    if (client === sender) return;
    client.write(message);
  });
  // Log it to the server output too
  process.stdout.write(message)
  }

  }).listen(3000);

   // Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
 console.log("server running at port 3000\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not socket.io, its something like tcp chat.

Just follow [these instructions](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and you will understand

**UPDATE**

*Objective:* send data through tcp-ip and obtain it through http in real-time.

To achieve this we have to go through several steps:

- create tcp server (you already have it)
- create socket.io server (if you don't need realtime, if page refresh is ok to get new data - usual http server is enought)
- create shared memory between two servers (or database storage as option)

I'll write pseudo-js code, just for you to understand how you can achieve it:

```
const app = require('express')()
const MESSAGES = []
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send(MESSAGES)
})
app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('server started'))

// and your code.. I won't repeat just a sample
// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function (data) {
  MESSAGES.push(data)
  broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket)
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.I have a device which uses TCP-IP to communicate with the server.The device sends its data to IP and port given and my above server side code also shows data received in the console window, I am finding hard to display it on the index.html page.I tried many examples but all display messages only if passed through browser

Comment: Ok, you want using that device to see in the web?

Comment: Yes, I want that device to see in the web like that web page is use to monitor data coming from the device.is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I want real-time data but am so sorry I am still finding your answer difficult to understand, can you please explain in detail.why I should use two servers and how this ` res.send(MESSAGES)` statement is used to display on the web

Comment: 1 server is serving tcp-ip connections, 2nd is serving http connections. I suggest you go with usual web and when you get it, switch to real-time with socket.io. As far as you run, type in browser: http://localhost:3000/, on the machine server is running, not device. To run on device you'll have to deploy it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145206/discussion-between-r-zeiwald-and-lazyexpert).